# multiple count(DISTINCT(..))s calculation

Tags: postgresql

I have following table schema

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
  id1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  id2 DATE NOT NULL,
  id3 INTEGER,
  val1 DOUBLE PRECISION,
  val2 DOUBLE PRECISION,
);
```

and i am using following query to perform aggregation on data

```
SELECT sum(val1)/count(DISTINCT(id1, id2)), sum(val2)/count(DISTINCT(id1, id2))
FROM dummmy
WHERE id1 IN (....) AND id2 IN (....)
GROUP BY id3;
```

since **count(DISTINCT(id1, id2))** expression is coming twice in the select clause will it be calculated twice ?

size of table is >10 millions.

will performance of below query be better than the earlier one ?

```
SELECT s1/s3, s2/s3
FROM (
    SELECT sum(val1) AS s1, sum(val2) AS s2, count(DISTINCT(id1, id2)) AS s3,
    FROM dummmy
    WHERE id1 IN (....) AND id2 IN (....)
    GROUP BY id3
) AS V1;
```

I am using postgresql-9.6

Thanks in anticipation !

Answer (score 0):

The performance of the second query will be better or equal than the performance of the first query since each expression will only be evaluated once, but I don't know if the difference will be significant.

You should test and examine the execution plans with `EXPLAIN`.